# manipulate headers on csv import ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

Aloha, as always, any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm importing a CSV and in the headers I have all caps and colons (for example, EXT:MAT:PIDTC is one).  How would I go about manipulating the headers on the way in?  maybe I want to change the example above to thisHeader or something to match up with my :thisHeader attribute in my SpiritTrial model.

```
class SpiritTrial < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
   SpiritTrial.create! row.to_hash
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSV.foreach` & co. take a `:header_converters` [option](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new), which should be a Proc or array of Procs that take a header as an argument and return a new value for that header. Given your example, you would do something like this:

```
class SpiritTrial < ActiveRecord::Base
  CSV_HEADER_MAP = {
    "EXT:MAT:PIDTC" => :thisHeader,
    # ...
  }

  CSV_HEADER_CONVERTER = ->(header) { HEADER_MAP.fetch(header, header).to_sym }

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: CSV_HEADER_CONVERTER) do |row|
      SpiritTrial.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

You can see an example sans Rails on repl.it: https://repl.it/FoAj